# The different bewteen MutableInteger and SynchronizedInteger ？

Tags: java, concurrency

I wrote the test case and hoped that the output will be different after adding the synchronized keyword. However, the output of the current output does not reflect the role of synchronized. I don't know what went wrong?

Chapter3 《Java Concurrentcy in Practice》 3.1.1

```java
//MutableInteger (Chapter3 《Java Concurrentcy in Practice》)

@NotThreadSafe
public class MutableInteger{
    private int value;
    public       int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public       void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MutableInteger getAndset = new MutableInteger();
        Thread setValue8 = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("8:  start set 8");
                getAndset.setValue(8);
                System.out.println("8:   set 8 over and start get value ");
                System.out.println( getAndset.getValue());
                System.out.println("8:   get value over");
            }
        };

        Thread setValue10 = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("10:  start set 10");
                getAndset.setValue(10);
                System.out.println("10:  set 10 over");
            }

        };

        setValue8.start();
        setValue10.start();
    }


}
```

Possible output: 
output1:

`8:  start set 8
10:  start set 10
8:   set 8 over and start get value 
10:  set 10 over
10
8:   get value over`

output2:

`10:  start set 10
8:  start set 8
10:  set 10 over
8:   set 8 over and start get value 
8
8:   get value over`

output3:

`8:  start set 8
8:   set 8 over and start get value 
8
8:   get value over
10:  start set 10
10:  set 10 over`

class SynchronizedInteger add synchronized

```java
import net.jcip.annotations.GuardedBy;
import net.jcip.annotations.ThreadSafe;

@ThreadSafe
public class SynchronizedInteger {
    @GuardedBy("this") private int value;
    public   synchronized    int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public   synchronized    void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SynchronizedInteger getAndset = new SynchronizedInteger();
        Thread setValue8 = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("8:  start set 8");
                getAndset.setValue(8);
                System.out.println("8:   set 8 over and start get value ");
                System.out.println( getAndset.getValue());
                System.out.println("8:   get value over");
            }
        };

        Thread setValue10 = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("10:  start set 10");
                getAndset.setValue(10);
                System.out.println("10:  set 10 over");
            }

        };

        setValue8.start();
        setValue10.start();
    }

}
```

Possible output: 
output1:

`8:  start set 8
8:   set 8 over and start get value 
8
8:   get value over
10:  start set 10
10:  set 10 over`

output2:

`8:  start set 8
8:   set 8 over and start get value 
8
8:   get value over
10:  start set 10
10:  set 10 over`

output3:

`8:  start set 8
10:  start set 10
8:   set 8 over and start get value 
10:  set 10 over
10
8:   get value over`

Comment: Why do your classes extend `Thread`? They are not threads. Anyway, since the set and get operations are *separately* synchronized, they do not prevent interleaving those operations.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I originally extended Thread to write a child thread and the main thread. Can I show test code about invalid data?                                        
 [ Non-thread-safe mutable integer holder.] (http://jcip.net/listings/SynchronizedInteger.java)
[Thread-safe mutable integer holder] (http://jcip.net/listings/MutableInteger.java)

Comment: Always add information in the question itself, not in the comments and not in links. Make sure the information that you add is minimal but complete for understanding of your problem.

Comment: Is your main method really the **same** is both cases? I hope you're using `SynchronizedInteger` in the latter main method?!